# eCommerce shop with data provided as CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

So I am a PHP developer really, I have only really used MySQL and some MSSQL datbases, as well as excel back in the day.

I have a client we are building an eCommerce shop for and he wants to save on the time it would take to data-input the products table. The list is provided by another company, think wholesale.

So they have given me a CSV file. a common entry looks like this.

```
"MAINCAT"^"SUBCAT"^355303^"10931"^"MANUFACTURER"^"Short Description"^"sgl"^"1"^1^.00^.00^.00^.00^.00^.00^6.79^"15561109314  5015561109314"^.20^"This is where the description goes"
```

I havn't got much experience with CSV files, but from stuff I've looked at, it seems a strange format, and some programmes don't even recognise it as a CSV file.

I have been unable to convert it into MySQL.

My question basically is, is there a way to utilise this CSV file, that will fit in with another PHP and MySQL drive eCommerce platform. ie. can it be easily converted, or utilised as a data platform that will be efficient.

Sorry if this isn't in the right place.

Comment: building your own, or installing one of the numerous, well developed open source existing scripts?

Comment: Platforms or frameworks we may use to build it havn't really been decided on, as the client would receive updates of products in this format, we are initially deciding if/how to make sure the database can be easily built and updated. If that makes sense. It will be PHP based though.

Comment: you can parse the above using the csv functions built in to php. many open source shopping sites have this sort of function built in. sounds like your putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that, thank you. This is maybe cheeky, but you have a recommendation?

Comment: i shy away from making such recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

This is hardly a csv file (comma separated values)

Try to convert it as you go, to match this explicit format.
Without knowing the data integrity, an example to make it CSV

```
$strange_lines = file('strange_csv.csv');

foreach ($strange_lines as $line) {
  echo str_replace(array('"^"','^"','"^','^'),',',$line).'<br>';
}
```

Comment: dont need to replace, the built in csv functions have a variable for the seperator